# Can Javascript Activity be used to add/update All Subscribers List?

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud

Can Javascript Activity be used to add to the All Subscribers List at the Enterprise Business Unit and update All Subscribers List at the Child Business Unit?

I was able to achieve this by creating an automation job in the Enterprise BU where I used Import activity to Add a Subscriber to the All Subscribers table. And another job in the Child BU to update the All Subscribers table. It is working just fine. I was interested in knowing if I could do the same using one javascript activity on the enterprise account and avoid the two automation jobs.

Comment: Could you give more description about a problem you faced?

Comment: I was able to achieve this by creating an automation job in the Enterprise BU where I used Import activity to Add a Subscriber to the All Subscribers table.  And another job in the Child BU to update the All Subscribers table.  It is working just fine.  I was interested in knowing if I could do the same using one javascript activity on the enterprise account and avoid the two automation jobs.